# Comparing contents of two spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have coped the contents of two different spreadsheets to one document – I need to compare the results of the two sheets (4 columns in each)

In the first group of 4 columns there are 3 entries for the 17th May and in the second group of 4 there are 4 entries – Patricia Nightingale is missing.

Is it feasible to write a script that highlights discrepancies in either sets? (ideally it would also compare the units)

This is quite a long spreadsheets (I have coipied the first 4 columns A - D and second Columns F - I)

I am not sure if this is possible but if it is could someone help me?

```
 Name           Date         Units   Service User 
 Alicia Haines  17 May 2016  1.00    Albert Nightingale 
 Alicia Haines  17 May 2016  0.50    Eve Reed 
 Alicia Haines  17 May 2016  0.75    Raymond Watson (Private) 
 Alicia Haines  18 May 2016  0.50    Albert Nightingale 
 Alicia Haines  18 May 2016  3.00    David Poole 
 Alicia Haines  18 May 2016  0.25    Eve Reed 

 Candidate      Date         Service User          Visit (mins)
 Alicia Haines  17 May 2016  Albert Nightingale    60
 Alicia Haines  17 May 2016  Eve Reed              30
 Alicia Haines  17 May 2016  Patricia Nightingale  15
 Alicia Haines  17 May 2016  Raymond Watson        45
 Alicia Haines  18 May 2016  Albert Nightingale    30
 Alicia Haines  18 May 2016  David Poole           180
```

Comment: Is creating helper columns an option for your worksheet structure?

Answer (score 0):

I had done this some time back. Basically I created the Excel sheets into a ODBC data source using administrator tool in windows. And then write Java code which uses ODBC connection to connect to the excel, then each sheet inside excel will become table. Then you can use SQL minus queries to perform comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will search the set1(column A to D) and return its result in I column. Similarly you can do this for set2(E to H Column).

```
Sub test()
    Dim flag As String, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    flag = "no"
    lastrow1 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim set1(lastrow1) As String
    ReDim set2(lastrow2) As String
    For i = 1 To lastrow1 - 1
        For j = 1 To 4
            If j <> 3 Then
                out = out & Cells(i + 1, j)
            End If
        Next j
        set1(i) = out
        out = ""
    Next i
    For i = 1 To lastrow2 - 1
        For j = 5 To 7
            out = out & Cells(i + 1, j)
        Next j
        set2(i) = out
        out = ""
    Next i
    For i = 1 To lastrow1
        For j = 1 To lastrow2
            If set1(i) = set2(j) Then
                flag = "yes"
            End If
        Next j
        If flag = "no" Then
            Range("I" & i + 1).Value = "Not Match"
            Range("D" & i + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Else
            flag = "no"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Proof of work**

[image]